# Let $I_n=\int_0^{\pi/2}x^2\cos^n(x)dx$ show that $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n-1)!!}I_{2n}=0$ and find $I_{2n}\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n-1)!!}$

Tags: calculus

Let $I_n=\int_0^{\pi/2}x^2\cos^n(x)dx$ show that $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n-1)!!}I_{2n}=0$

and show that $I_{2n}\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n-1)!!}=\frac{\pi^3}{24}-\frac{\pi}{4}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n^2}$

I found that $n(2n-1)I_{2n-2} - 2n^2I_{2n}=\frac{\pi(2n-1)!!}{2(2n)!!}$, but I don't know how to use this to find the limit or the formula above.

Comment: If you have managed to show that $I_{2n}\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n-1)!!}= \frac{\pi^3}{24} -\frac{\pi}{4}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^2}$, then the result $\boxed{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2} =\frac{\pi^2}{6}}$ may be helpful. See e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem) for more information about this series.

Comment: I don't know how to obtain that formula. I only managed to find the last one with integration by parts. Also I can't use that series because later I have to prove it using the formula from this problem.

Comment: You can find the formula using what you've found though I don't know how to find the liimt if you can't use that series.